# Getting the top and bottom margin to stay inside mat-grid-tile?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

[In this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-grid-tile-layout?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) the margin of the `div` sitting inside the tile is `2rem` however only the margin on the top and bottom extends outside the tile.

How do we get all the margins to stay inside the tile?

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" gutterSize="20px" rowHeight="200px">
    <mat-grid-tile>
        <div style="
      margin: 2rem;
      width: 100%; 
      height: 100%; 
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);"></div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-tile>

</mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could position the inner `<div>` with `absolute` and set `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` to 0;

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="2" gutterSize="20px" rowHeight="200px">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <div style="
      margin: 2rem;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);"></div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  ...
</mat-grid-list>
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-grid-tile-layout-7sjm3k

Comment: Sweet - Would you happen to know why the margin floats outside the tile without the absolute positioning?

Comment: It has something to do with the css positioning of `mat-grid-tile`.  Its set to absolute which take the element out of the normal flow of the document.  I don't know enough about CSS positioning to give you a proper answer though.